# Sql IF exists, Update & return new column as true, Else return column as false

Tags: sql

I am trying to validate user info, return a userExists column as true if they have a valid combo and update lastLogin time. Otherwise, just return false. I am getting an error on my ELSE statement.. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [User].Data WHERE username = @username 
               AND password = @password)
    UPDATE [User].Data
    SET    lastLogin = GETDATE()
    WHERE    username = @username

    SELECT 'true' AS userValid

ELSE
    SELECT 'false' AS userValid
END
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting... First post. ><

Comment: "getting an error"? What is the error? And what dialect of SQL are you using; not all support `IF`.

Comment: Is the error on the `else` statement or on the `end` statement?  You have no `begin`, so the dangling `end` looks suspect.

Comment: Sorry guys, I missed the top of the SPROC. It's TSQL and I had two variable declarations and BEGIN AS preceding the post. TheVillage has the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `begin` and `end` like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [User].Data WHERE username = @username 
               AND password = @password)
BEGIN --BEGIN IF BLOCK
    UPDATE [User].Data
    SET    lastLogin = GETDATE()
    WHERE    username = @username

    SELECT 'true' AS userValid
END --END IF BLOCK
ELSE
    SELECT 'false' AS userValid
END
```

As there are no braces or indentations in SQL, you have to demarcate blocks of `IF` with multiple statements using `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple! :D